# Does git revert only take previous commit-hash, and for others we need to use HEAD~3 syntax?

Tags: git, github, git-bash, git-revert

I

I am providing git revert 5thCommitHashFromHead, it says auto-merging, I removed conflicts from code editor, it still shows master|reverting, but when I provided git revert HEAD~5 it works fine, do we need to use only HEAD~number Syntax with revert?

Comment: Not sure I understand what the problem is. If what you are not understanding is _why_ you are still in `master|reverting`, it is because you haven't.... _finished_. You need to add the files after you have solved the conflicts and run `git revert --continue`. The question about why it behaves different if you run `git revert HEAD~5` it's probably because it's a different commit that you are dealing with there.... take a look at the commit id and it should be dfifferent: `git rev-parse HEAD~5`

Comment: And if the ID is indeed different from what you use as `5thCommitHashFromHead` and you wonder how that is possible then the question becomes: how did you find the commit id that you are using as `5thCommitHashFromHead`?

Comment: Whether you're giving a branch name, a commit hash, a tag, or a relative ref (like `HEAD~3`), in the end git reduces it to a commit hash and uses that. If your two revert commands behave differently, it's because of the difference between commits you're reverting.